# .next() not working for .toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery's `toggle()` function to create a pull-down menu, but I will add many sub-menus in this project.

I need to click the `a.sub_open` to toggle the `div.submenu`.

https://jsfiddle.net/mr6b4k53/

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".sub_open" ).click(function() {
        $(".sub_menu").next.toggle("blind", 0, 500);
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

#### Edit1:

I have tried using `next()` but still the issue exists. Can you please suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: 1. it's`next()` not `next`.2. need to use `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Please do not update question based on suggestions in comments/answer. Updating will make them unnecessary/invalid.

Comment: thanks, but next is my entry error. I use next(). still cannot work

Comment: Nominated for reopening. OP says `.next` was not the problem

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca That might be but updating in original code will make current answers invalid. I have added a *edit* section

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thanks for your guide so much.

Comment: @Sky define "Not working" and "Still not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` and `next()` like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".sub_open" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next(".sub_menu").toggle("blind", 0, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.sub_menu{
  background:#232323;
  color:#fff;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="sub_open">aaa</a>
      <div class="sub_menu"><p>text the sub_menu</p></div>
    </li>

    <li><a href="">bbb</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="sub_open">ccc</a>
      <div class="sub_menu"><p>text the sub_menu</p></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">ddd</a></li>
    <li><a href="">eee</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Working fiddle also:-https://jsfiddle.net/xhtw28wb/

***NOTE:-*** make sure that jQuery library is added before your script code.

Comment: Alive, Thanks for your patiently guide!

Comment: @Sky  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 4):

`next` is a function, but you have used as a field or property. Call it also via `$(this)`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".sub_open" ).click(function() {
         $(this).next().toggle("blind", 0, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` is a chainable function, use it like so:

`$(".sub_menu").next().toggle("blind", 0, 500);`

Comment: that my enter mistakes.I use next(). still cannot work